# Dropping Unique Constraint - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, relational-database

**TL;DR**

I am seeking clarity on this: does a `FOREIGN KEY` require a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the other side, specifically, in Postgres and, generally, in relational database systems?

Perhaps, I can test this, but I'll ask, if the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is required by the `FOREIGN KEY` what would happen if I don't create it? Will the Database create one or will it throw an error?

**How I got there**

I had earlier on created a table with a column `username` on which I imposed a unique constraint. I then created another table with a column `bearer_name` having a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing the previous table's column `username`; the one which had a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

Now, I want to drop the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the `username` column from the database because I have later on created a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the same column and intuitively I feel that they serve the same purpose, or don't they? But the database is complaining that the `UNIQUE INDEX` has some dependent objects and so it can't be dropped unless I provide `CASCADE` as an option in order to drop even the dependent object. It's identifying the `FOREIGN KEY` on `bearer_name` column in the second table as the dependent object.

And is it possible for the `FOREIGN KEY` to be a point to the `UNIQUE INDEX` instead of the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am seeking clarity on this: does a FOREIGN KEY require a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the other side

No it does not require only `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. It could be `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX`.

> Perhaps, I can test this, but I'll ask, if the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT is required by the FOREIGN KEY what would happen if I don't create it? **Will the Database create one or will it throw an error?**

```
CREATE TABLE tab_a(a_id INT, b_id INT);
CREATE TABLE tab_b(b_id INT);

ALTER TABLE tab_a ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tab_a_tab_b FOREIGN KEY (b_id)  
             REFERENCES tab_b(b_id);
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys 
        for referenced table "tab_b"
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a07ae1d4c777fe3e574f97269b3e6ae2)**

> And is it possible for the FOREIGN KEY to be a point to the UNIQUE INDEX instead of the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT?

Yes, it is possible.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tab_b_i ON tab_b(b_id);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e6783640803d83a8f813538d51b5ae1)**